# pasar contenido de un campo de archivo json a una varibale en powershell

Tags: json, variables, powershell

Tengo un archivo json y deseo pasar el valor de un campo a una variable
el archivo json tiene la siguiente estructura

```
{
    "actions": {
       "send_dian": false,
       "send_email": false
     },
   "invoice": {
      "number": "990001344",
      "invoice_type_code": "FACTURA_VENTA",
      "numbering": {
         "resolution_number": "18760000001",
           "prefix": "MSTL",
           "flexible": true
          },
      "customer": {
           "email": "TOROFABIAN@GMAIL.COM",
           "phone": "3136490333",
           "company_name": "LUIS FABIAN TORO GUTIERREZ"
         }
     }
   }
```

y deseo pasar el valor del campo number a un variable asi:

```
$archivo = "archivo1.json"
$body = Get-Content $archivo 
$numerofolio1 = $body.psobject.properties["number"].value
Write-Host "numero de folio:" $numerofolio1
$numerofolio1

$numerofolio2 = $body.psobject.properties["invoice.number"].value
Write-Host "numero de folio:" $numerofolio2
$numerofolio2
```

pero ninguna de las dos formas me envia el valor de number

como se debe de hacer?
Gracias

Comment: Necesitas usar el Convertfrom-Json para tranformar el contenido del archivo de JSON a un objeto.  [ver help en ingles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.2)

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas convertir el contenido del archivo en un objeto.  El comando ConvertFrom-Json sirve para esto.

```
$body = get-content archivo1.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$numerofolio2 = $body.invoice.number

$numerofolio2
```